# jQuery add content to element without id

Tags: jquery

I want to add text to a rich:editor inside the `<p>...</p>` elements by using jQuery. The HTML looks like this:

[image]

How can I add text by using this command (I need to modify existing code).

```
jQuery("????????????").text(data.dataMap["error.message"]);
```

Comment: Have you tried `$("p").text()` ??

Comment: How does jquery know that I want to modify exactly this p. Maybe there are other ps around? I guess I need to identify the p inside the body with these classes shown above.

Comment: Which classes? the ones on body? I think you need to add more details to your question. The current description invites a lot of wrong answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the only paragraph containing a `br` with `type="_moz"`, then the selector is `p:has(br[type=_moz])` (a [type selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#type-selectors) with jQuery's [`:has` combinator](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/), with a type selector combined with an [attribute value selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-representation) inside).

Or of course, it's the first paragraph in the body, so `body p:first` or `body p:eq(0)`.

Otherwise, you'll have to find other aspects about it that let you target it uniquely (other attributes, where it is, what comes before, what comes after, what it has in it, etc.).

Comment: type=_moz is for br not for p?

Comment: @Adil: We should clean up these comments. :-)

Comment: Did I understand this right that I only have to add this to my jQuery command like this? `jQuery("p:has(br[type=_moz]").text(data.dataMap["error.message"]);`
(If yes, then I have another problem too, because it doesn't add the text.)

Comment: @Bevor: Yes, except you're missing a `)` inside the string in that (after `]`). It would be `jQuery("p:has(br[type=_moz])").text...`: Example: http://jsbin.com/genosiku/1 (source: http://jsbin.com/genosiku/1/edit).